# I want to have multiple values in an if statement in Python

Tags: python

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. Any assistance is appreciated, sorry for the rookie question.

```
if input_num != 8 or 16 or 32 or 64 or 128 or 256:
    #some function
```

I think the problem is the 'or', I don't think this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: `if input_num not in [8,16,32,64,128,256]:`

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the statement every time so like this:

```
if input_num != 8 and input_num != 16 and input_num != 32 and input_num != 64 and input_num != 128 and input_num != 256:
```